# My Service won't stop even if is onDestroy fired

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service

I have a `Service` that acts like a `TimerTask` and even if I stop the service using :

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, TimeService::class.java)
stopService(intent)
```

It doesn't stop, I have a `Log` in `onDestroy` and this `Log` is fired... but I think the problem is that I'm using a `TimerTask` inside the `Service` this is my `Service`

```
class TimeService : Service() {
    private val mHandler = Handler()
    var calendar: Calendar? = null
    var simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat? = null
    var strDate: String? = null
    var date_current: Date? = null
    var date_diff: Date? = null
    private var mTimer: Timer? = null
    private val NOTIFY_INTERVAL: Long = 1000
    var intent: Intent? = null

    companion object {
        val str_receiver = "myreceiver"
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()


        calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())

        mTimer = Timer()
        mTimer!!.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL)
        intent = Intent(str_receiver)
    }

    internal inner class TimeDisplayTimerTask : TimerTask() {

        override fun run() {
            mHandler.post {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
                strDate = simpleDateFormat!!.format(calendar!!.time)
                Log.e("strDate", strDate)
                twoDatesBetweenTime()
            }
        }

    }

    fun twoDatesBetweenTime(): String {


        try {
            date_current = simpleDateFormat!!.parse(strDate)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }

        try {
            date_diff = simpleDateFormat!!.parse(SharedPreferenceHelper.defaultPrefs(this).getString("data", ""))
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }

        try {


            val diff = date_current!!.time - date_diff!!.time
            val timeInSeconds = Integer.valueOf(SharedPreferenceHelper.defaultPrefs(this).getString("seconds", "")!!)

            val timeTimer = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(timeInSeconds.toLong())
            val diffWithTime = timeTimer - diff
            val diffSeconds2 = diffWithTime / 1000 % 60
            val diffMinutes2 = diffWithTime / (60 * 1000) % 60
            val diffHours2 = diffWithTime / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24


            if (diffWithTime >= 0) {
                val counterTime = "$diffHours2  :  $diffMinutes2 : $diffSeconds2"

                Log.e("TIME", counterTime)

                fn_update(counterTime)
            } else {
                SharedPreferenceHelper.defaultPrefs(this).edit().putBoolean("finish", true).apply()
                mTimer!!.cancel()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            mTimer!!.cancel()
            mTimer!!.purge()


        }

        return ""

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.e("Service finish", "Finish")
    }

    private fun fn_update(str_time: String) {

        intent!!.putExtra("time", str_time)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}
```

And the problem is that this log :

```
Log.e("strDate", strDate)
```

And this log :

```
Log.e("TIME", counterTime)
```

Never stops, what I'm missing?

### EDIT

My approach is this from the moment but I don't know if it's the best way :

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.e("Service finish", "Finish")
    if(mTimer!=null){
        mTimer!!.cancel()
        mTimer!!.purge()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OnDestroy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onDestroy()) is a callback method invoked by system to allow your service a "clean exit":

> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead. Do not call this method directly.

System does not instantly terminate your app process following this callback. It's up to You to kill the `TimerTask` at this point. If You leave it running it's considered a leak. Most likely it will keep running until system decides it's time to kill Your apps process which might take a while if it's kept in the foreground.

Comment: @StuartDTO looks fine, but You should look into changing your `mTimer`, `calendar` and `simpleDateFormat` to `lateinit var` instead of performing dirty non null casts (`!!`) thorough your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;)